# Magento CE - Google Certified Shops UK

Tags: magento-1.9

I am in the process of implementing google certified shops on our magento CE site in the UK.

I have completed most of the testing but am struggling with the order confirmation module. I have sorted the following code from another stack over flow tutorial (really sorry but I cannot remember which otherwise I would link and give credit)

```
<?php
    $orderId = $this->getOrderId();
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($order->getCustomerId());
    $address = $order->getShippingAddress();
    $backorder = false; // some backorder logic
    $download = false; // some download logic
    $shipDate = new Zend_Date(); // some logic to determine ship date
?>
<!-- START Trusted Stores Order -->
<div id="gts-order" style="display:none;">

<!-- start order and merchant information -->
<span id="gts-o-id"><?php echo $orderId; ?></span>
<span id="gts-o-domain">{www.ourwebaddress.com}</span>
<span id="gts-o-email"><?php echo htmlentities($customer->getEmail()); ?></span>
<span id="gts-o-country"><GB></span>
<span id="gts-o-currency">GBP</span>
<span id="gts-o-total"><?php echo $order->getGrandTotal(); ?></span>
<span id="gts-o-discounts">-<?php echo $order->getDiscountAmount(); ?></span>
<span id="gts-o-shipping-total"><?php echo $order->getShippingAmount(); ?></span>
<span id="gts-o-tax-total"><?php echo $order->getTaxAmount(); ?></span>
<span id="gts-o-est-ship-date"><?php echo $shipDate->toString('yyyy-MM-dd'); ?></span>
<span id="gts-o-has-preorder"><N></span>
<span id="gts-o-has-digital"><N></span>
<!-- end order and merchant information -->

<!-- start repeated item specific information -->
<?php foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item): ?>
<span class="gts-item">
<span class="gts-i-name"><?php echo htmlentities($item->getName()); ?></span>
<span class="gts-i-price"><?php echo $item->getBasePrice(); ?></span>
<span class="gts-i-quantity"><?php echo (int)$item->getQtyOrdered(); ?></span>
<span class="gts-i-prodsearch-country">US</span>
<span class="gts-i-prodsearch-language">en</span>
</span>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<!-- end repeated item specific information -->

</div>
<!-- END Trusted Stores -->
```

And have placed it on the app/design/frontend/{your}/{theme}/template/checkout/success.phtml
page.

Could anyone provide any advice as to why it is not working?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is wrong with your code, but you should definitely have a look at the [free and open source Google Trusted Stores extension by Develo Design](https://github.com/develodesign/magento-google-trusted-stores). I use it for a shop, which is now a Google trusted store. I also contributed some code to the extension and my changes were merged nearly instantly. So this extension seems to be nicely supported and maintained.

Comment: How easy are the modman / git or subversion to use for installing extensions?

Comment: If you have an existing shop without modman, it takes quite some time to convert it to use modman (depending on the number of extensions + themes). But you can also simply drop the files at the right place in your shop. In any case, you should use a VCS like git or subversion.